# Python- For loop for x amount of times, with info in the loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

I am trying to loop through a piece of info for a x  amount of times, but I can't seem to make it work with range() or isslice. I want to be able to say that the code within the loop are only looped x amount of times.

The loop I would like to loop trough x amount of times:

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
x = soup.find("div", class_="object-list-items-container")


for child in x.findChildren("section", recursive=False):
        if "U heeft gereageerd" in child.text:
            continue
        else:
            house_id = child.find("div", {'class': 'ng-scope'}).get("id")
            driver.find_element_by_id(house_id).click()
```

I've read quite some stack overflow questions but i'm probably not experienced enough to implement it for my situation. I have tried a couple of things, but nothing worked so far.

I've tried the following:

("reacties" is the variable for the x amount of times it needs to loop)

```
for i in range(reacties):
    for child in x.findChildren("section", recursive=False):
        if "U heeft gereageerd" in child.text:
            continue
        else:
          ...........
```

and:

```
for i in range(reacties):
    child= x.findChildren("section", recursive=False)
    if "U heeft gereageerd" in child.text:
         continue
    else:
        ...............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterate `n` times, based on shortest iterator.

```
for i, child in zip(range(x), x.findChildren("section", recursive=False)):
    if "U heeft gereageerd" in child.text:
         continue
    else:
        ...............
```

Answer (score 2):

You can incorporate `enumerate` functionality.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate
For example:

```
for count, child in enumerate(x.findChildren("section", recursive=False)):
    If count > reacties:
        break
    if "U heeft gereageerd" in child.text:
        continue
    else:
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make an iterator.

```
import itertools

it = itertools.repeat(x.findChildren("section", recursive=False), times=n)

for child in it:
    #do your job
```

Comment: The goal is to use the first `n` items contained within `x.findChildren("section", recursive=False)`; **not** to use `x.findChildren("section", recursive=False)` `n` times.